# Filter Array Using Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to filter an array (courses) by a property, FacilityId.

I am getting a response back for all of my $http calls in my controller which is as follows:

```
function holeIndexController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.facilities = [];
    $scope.courses = [];
    $scope.holes = [];

    getFacilities();
    getCourses();
    getHoles();

    function getFacilities() {
        $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/api/facility'
            }).
            success(function(result) {
                $scope.facilities = result;
            }).error(function () {
                console.log("Error: " + result.ExceptionMessage);
                alert("Could not load facilities");
            });
    }

    $scope.courseByFacility = function (facilities) {
        return function(courses) {
            return course.facilityId === facility.facilityId;
        };
    };

    function getCourses() {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/api/course'
        }).
        success(function (result) {
            $scope.courses = result;
        }).error(function (result) {
            console.log("Error: " + result.ExceptionMessage);
            alert("Could not load courses");
        });
    }

    function getHoles() {
        $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/api/hole'
            }).
            success(function(result) {
                getFacilities();
                $scope.holes = result;
            }).error(function(result) {
                console.log("Error: " + result.ExceptionMessage);
                alert("Could not load courses");
            });
    }

}
```

And my HTML is as follows:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="f in facilities">
            Facility: {{f.Name}}
            <div data-ng-repeat="c in courses | filter: coursesByFacility">
                Course: {{c.Name}}
            </div>
        </div>
```

What is the best way to filter courses by their respective FacilityId's?

Comment: I may be doing this wrong but I am looking to get a list of facilities with all courses listed underneath each facility.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the facility into the filter function, like:

```
<div ng-repeat="c in courses | filter:coursesByFacility(f)">
```

Also, your `coursesByFacility` function takes a `courses` parameter, but then you're trying to act upon `course` (no s).  Change this to this:

```
$scope.coursesByFacility = function(facility) {
  return function(course) {
    return course.facilityId === facility.facilityId;
  }
}
```

See this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/gilohutu/1/)

*Edit: Didn't realize the jsbin link was going to strip all the code so you can't see it.  Anyways, just view the source, it's minimal and easy to read*

Comment: This did not work.  I am still fetching the entire list of courses under each facility.  Would I pass in the entire object or just the FacilityId?

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle/jsbin?  If you look at mine, it's working.  You must be doing something different

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function called getCoursesByFacility() which has a facilityId parameter.  The function should iterate through the list of courses and build an array of courses with that facilityId, then return the list.  You would then need to call the function from your javascript.  Something like this should work:

```
    <div data-ng-repeat="f in facilities">
        Facility: {{f.Name}}
        <div data-ng-repeat="c in getCoursesByFacility(f.facilityId)">
            Course: {{c.Name}}
        </div>
    </div>
```